# Is it possible to expand related entities using $expand on OData v4 function?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I know it is possible to $expand on normal GET over entities, but what about OData functions? It seems $expand does not expand related entity when used on OData function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Just make sure that:

- Your function implementation in the controller is decorated with the [EnableQuery] attribute.
- You are returning an IQueryable enumeration.

Optionally, you can wrap it in an IHttpActionResult response.